# How to runtime trace gcc/clang?

Tags: gcc, clang, runtime, trace

I want to trace all the user functions in `gcc`/`clang` when running something like `gcc test.c`.

> noted that I want to trace the functions in `gcc` or `clang` not that in `test.c`

Some tools like `strace` and `ltrace` can only trace system calls or library functions, and tools like [etrace](https://github.com/elcritch/etrace) need re-compile the program I want to trace (i.e. re-compile `gcc`/`clang`). What's more, using `gdb` also have to re-compile `gcc`/`clang` to debug binaries. **However**, compiling `gcc`/`clang` is extremely expensive and error-prone. So is there any short cuts to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Without debug symbols you (or any tracing tool) won't know which machine code goes with which source-level function.

Comment: Compiling gcc is much more affordable under `--disable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++` (also may make sense to not build rt libs by making with `make -C gcc`).